# David Williams "Probability with Martingales" 6.10 : Fatou's lemma in proof of $L^p$ completeness

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The proof of $L^p$ completensss in the book is as follows:

[image]

My question: How is Fatou's lemma used , precisely, in the above proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line before the highlighted text tells you that
$$ \mathbb{E}(|X_r-X_{k_t}|^p)\leq 2^{-np} $$
for all $t\in\mathbb{N}$, and since $|X_r-X_{k_t}|^p\geq 0$ and $|X_r-X_{k_t}|^p\to |X_r-X|^p$ almost surely as $t\to\infty$, we can apply Fatou's lemma to conclude that
$$ \mathbb{E}(|X_r-X|^p)\leq \liminf_{t\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(|X_r-X_{k_t}|^p)\leq 2^{-np} $$

Comment: I see it now thank you for your time !